# Feature of VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xna

Is there a feature in VS 2010 that allows me to look at the value of a variable when it changes.
Like suppose I have a `data type bool` and its value is `false` and when its value changes to `true` I get into debugging mode or Another scenario is that I have a `data type int` and when its value changes I get into debugging mode.

The main reason I am asking this question is because I want to check value in my XNA game in Update method, and as Update method execute 60 time/sec so its kinda hard to do it in debugging mode.

Comment: Conditional breakpoints - and in particular "has changed" - can impact performance, though. Personally, I'd simply make sure all changes to the variable come through one route (a set accessor or set method) - and put a *regular* breakpoint there (perhaps after a "compare the old/proposed value" check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a condition on the Breakpoint

[Right-Click the Breakpoint] -> Condition

In the condition field you can either type a simple variable and have the breakpoint hit if it's value change or you can enter a boolean expression that breaks in to debug mode if that expression is true.

It comes in handy in iterations, but also comes with a performance penalty. I'm not an XNA guy so you might be better off implementing some Debug support that does the conditional check, maybe guarded with a DEBUG conditional check:

```
int value = 0;
// some stuff changing value
#if DEBUG
   if (value == 42)
   {
         Debug.WriteLine(value); // set a breakpoint on this line
   }

#endif
```

Condensed based on this blog [Msdn VS2010 Tips and Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition-vstipdebug0021.aspx) that also comes with screenshots.